# magento 2 - how to override full flow of Configurable product in custom side

Tags: magento2

I want to **override full admin grid about configurable product** in custom side in magento 2

Can you give me path of all files which affect configurable product admin side?

Answer (score 1):

The files are affected for configurable products in admin side.

```
vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\view\adminhtml\web\css\configurable-product.css

vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\view\adminhtml\web\js\configurable-type-handler.js

vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\view\adminhtml\web\js\configurable.js

vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\view\adminhtml\templates\catalog\product\composite\fieldset\configurable.phtml

vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\view\adminhtml\ui_component\configurable_associated_product_listing.xml    

vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Composite\Fieldset\Configurable.php

vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper\Plugin\Configurable.php

vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\Model\Order\Admin\Item\Plugin\Configurable.php
```

Please use only required files for your customization.

Comment: sir , where it is in magento 2.1.3 "module-configurable-product-staging"

Comment: I update my code now.pls check it

Comment: Sir Vino,can u tell me which XML file bind all files to create configurable product so i can override that file in my custom module at front-end side.Exactly i want to create configurable button and on click on that button open side modal perform all steps to create configurable product in my custom module .